# Setting value of an indexed Variable to an indexed Expression - pyomo

Tags: python, for-loop, runtime, pyomo

I am working on a project which require me to code with a python lib. called pyomo.

and I need to set value of an indexed Variable to an indexed Expression.

So there is 2 models on total and 1 script which creates their instances.

First Model:

```
m.i = [1,2,3]    # i=1,2,3
m.j = [1,2,3]    # j=1,2,3

m.index = Set(within=m.i*m.j)    # m.index = [i]*[j] (pyomo set)

m.a = Var(m.index)    # m.a[i,j]

m.Exp = Expression(m.index)    # pyomo expression with [i,j] index

m.Const = Constraint(m.index, rule=const_rule)

def const_rule(m, index):
    return m.a[index] == m.Exp[index]
```

Second Model:

```
m.index = ...         # same index with first model's m.index
m.y = Var(m.index)    # lets assume it has values or I can put with init command
```

the run.py Script:

```
instance1 = create_first_model()
instance2 = create_second model()

solve(instance2)

for k in instance1.index:                                    
    instance1.Exp[k].expr = instance2.y[k].value

solve(instance1)
```

Shortly:

I need a better approach for this for-loop. or more efficient approach (loops are slow...)

Regards
Okan

Ps: all of the vars, sets, expression and constraint are pyomo objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is m.Exp an expression containing Pyomo variables or are you using as a constant (i.e. a mutable parameter)?

Assuming that it is an expression and you want to add a constraint based on the expression in your for-loop, the following should work:

```
def _linking_con(m, k):
    return m.Exp[k] == value(instance2.y[k])
instance1.linking_con = Constraint(instance1.index, rule=_linking_con)
```

If m.Exp is a constant value then I would replace it with a mutable Param

```
m.Exp = Param(m.index, mutable=True)
```

And then change your for-loop to:

```
for k in instance1.index:
    instance1.Exp[k] = value(instance2.y[k])
```

I don't think there is a way to avoid the for-loop

Comment: I am using it as mutual parameter, but I did not code it like that because otherwise solver does not give any dual variable from that constraint.

Comment: Also if I put _linking_con inside any models they won't work because instance's are not created before calling the models and therefore it will give an error while calling models which will be like instance2.y[k] is not exist.

Comment: You can add the constraint after both models are constructed